Driving 5 and 3.3 V square wave from a single terminal
I'm quite new to the topic and for fun I'm building a low frequency square wave generator with parts I currently have. Overall it works just fine while built on a breadboard, however I would like to add a feature that would allow both 5 and 3.3 V square wave output, while the circuit is powered with 5 V.
Please have a look at the circuit attached. In particular, I'm interested in the circuitry around J1 connector and OUT_NR. OUT_NR is a 74LS74 flip-flop Q output, which is producing 1-256 Hz square wave signal.
I do not have a buffer IC, so to deliver 3.3 V signal from OUT_NR I'm using 2 inverters and a Zener diode.
I would like both signals to be able to go HIGH and LOW, that means that J1 connector 5 and 3.3 V terminals should be able to source and sink current.
The goal is to deliver clock signal to other TTL and CMOS "Clocked" ICs like shift registers or provide external clock signal to MCUs, so we are talking about relatively low current.
There are couple of questions I would like to ask:

I want to get rid of the 74LS04 (inverter IC) and replace it with simple passive components, but as for now buffer or inverter IC is the only solution I came up with. Any other options I've tried either affect OUT_NR 5 V output or do not allow current to go from one of the outputs back to the ground through a flip-flop when Q goes low.

Once buffer (inverter) is removed, can you suggest a way to have J1 connector as a SIL2 instead of SIL3 and pick between 3.3 and 5 V with a 3 terminal switch?


Your help is much appreciated.


How will the two square wave outputs be applied? What are the worst case loads you expect to drive with them? How much current must they deal with when LO or when HI?

What are your requirements on frequency and raise and fall times? Lately I experienced slow edges just because of the used resistors, which had a too high inductance.

@periblepsis, thanks for your comment, I've added this information to the question. The goal is to deliver clock signal to other "Clocked" ICs like shift registers or provide external clock signal to MCUs, so we are talking about relatively low current.

Did you consider an actual level converter? If so, why did you not go that way?

Hello @thebusybee thank you for your comments. This is definitely an option but I wanted to avoid additional ICs like buffer or logic level shifter. I think another option is to get 3.3 V signal from the alternate flip-flop output by adding voltage divider to /Q of U3:A. In this case 3.3 and 5 V signals will be out of phase, however I do not need them to be used simultaneously. Since most of the clock inputs are triggered on raising edge, I should be good.

@MaximPavlov There are so many different possibilities crossing my mind at this point and some of these include off-board uses. You say you want to avoid buffer/logic level shifters -- but provide NO reasoning at all. Just statement by fiat. One might suggest a simple FET or BJT and a pair of resistors (3 for extra benefit.) But I suspect you won't like that, either, for reasons I also won't be told. I don't like throwing mud at a wall to see what sticks. Aimless. But here's a thought: use a 7406 or 7407. 30 V tolerances, 40 mA sink, OC type output. TTL input. In any case, need more from you.

@MaximPavlov For more tossing of mud, look here and talk about what's wrong there. Etc.

@periblepsis, thanks for sharing more examples. With the input you've provided the question can be considered as closed.

@periblepsis, To your point, this is one of the first designs I'm doing after taking some courses in electronics, and while coming from software development world, I'm looking for a way to keep things as simple as possible. The motivation can be re-phrased in the following way: why would I use a heavy track (IC) to bring milk from a grocery store. Thanks for sharing your feedback.

@MaximPavlov I'm from the software world, having developed timesharing operating systems in the early '70s and learning C while working on the Unix v6 kernel in 1978 to dependency injected C# MTA applications today. I'm just glad you closed this. What you just added makes me regret time spent.

That's going to be a bit difficult.
Mostly because you are using 74LS TTL logic IC.
With a 5V supply and some load on output, it might not even output 3.3V as a high logic level, and certainly won't output 5V.
So to even get a 5V output, often there is just a pull-up resistor to 5V. So this is the easy part.
It will be more difficult to make it output 3.3V. Of course a pull-up resistor to 3.3V could be used, but the chip might output slightly more than 3.3V. What you could do is to put a 220 ohm pull-up to 5V and 330 ohm pull-down to make a voltage divider with 3.3V output. It will make the output float quite strongly at 3.3V and the weak chip output trying to push it high can't raise the voltage much over 3.3V, but will still sink enough current to strongly pull the voltage down to logic 0 levels.
So it might just be that the 5V output and 3.3V output could share the 220 ohm pull-up and a switch could then add the 330 ohm pull-down to select 3.3V.
